# React Native build release: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to build an archive of my app developed in react native.

I keep getting the following error though:

[image]

I've browsed similar issues on github, like this one:
https://github.com/react-community/react-native-maps/issues/1691 but it's not relevant to my issue since I don't use maps.

I bet some of you have already came through this hell with releasing RN app, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

yes i am in this hell to! i think you have to do this:
xcode > your target > remove -IGTMSessionFetcher library from Libraries folder and "Linked Framwork and Libraries" section,hope this help

Comment: Thanks bro. Really helped a lot. We have been scratching our heads for 8 straight hours and finally we found your answer.